# Can BOOST_PP_DEFINED be implemented?

Tags: c++, boost, macros, c-preprocessor, boost-preprocessor

Is it possible to write a function-like C preprocessor macro that returns `1` if its argument is defined, and `0` otherwise? Lets call it `BOOST_PP_DEFINED` by analogy with the other boost preprocessor macros, which we can assume are also in play:

```
#define BOOST_PP_DEFINED(VAR) ???

#define XXX
BOOST_PP_DEFINED(XXX)  // expands to 1
#undef XXX
BOOST_PP_DEFINED(XXX)  // expands to 0
```

I'm expecting to use the result of `BOOST_PP_DEFINED` with `BOOST_PP_IIF`:

```
#define MAGIC(ARG) BOOST_PP_IIF(BOOST_PP_DEFINED(ARG), CHOICE1, CHOICE2)
```

In other words, I want the expansion of `MAGIC(ARG)` to vary based on whether `ARG` is defined or not at the time that `MAGIC` is expanded:

```
#define FOO
MAGIC(FOO)  // expands to CHOICE1 (or the expansion of CHOICE1)
#undef FOO
MAGIC(FOO)  // expands to CHOICE2 (or the expansion of CHOICE2)
```

I also found it interesting (and somewhat surprising) that the following *doesn't* work:

```
#define MAGIC(ARG) BOOST_PP_IIF(defined(arg), CHOICE1, CHOICE2)
```

Because apparently `defined` is only valid in the preprocessor when used as part of an `#if` expression.

I somewhat suspect that the fact that boost preprocessor doesn't already offer `BOOST_PP_DEFINED` is evidence for its impossibility, but it can't hurt to ask. Or, am I missing something really obvious about how to achieve this.

**EDIT**: To add some motivation, here is why I want this. The traditional way to do "API" macros to control import/export is to declare a new set of macros for every library, which means a new header, etc. So if we have `class Base` in `libbase` and `class Derived` in `libderived`, then we have something like the following:

```
// base_config.hpp
#if LIBBASE_COMPILING
#define LIBBASE_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LIBBASE_API __declspec(dllimport)

// base.hpp
#include "base_config.hpp"
class LIBBASE_API base {
public:
    base();
};

// base.cpp
#include "base.hpp"
base::base() = default;

// derived_config.hpp
#if LIBDERIVED_COMPILING
#define LIBDERIVED_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define LIBDERIVED_API __declspec(dllimport)

// derived.hpp
#include "derived_config.hpp"
#include "base.hpp"
class LIBDERIVED_API derived : public base {
public:
    derived();
};

// derived.cpp
#include "derived.hpp"
derived::derived() = default;
```

Now, obviously, each of the `_config.hpp` header would really be a lot more complex, defining several macros. We could probably pull out some of the commonalities into a generic `config_support.hpp` file, but not all. So, in an effort to simplify this mess, I wondered if it would be possible make this generic, so that one set of macros could be used, but that would expand differently based on which `_COMPILING` macros were in play:

```
// config.hpp
#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#define IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)

#define API_IMPL2(COND) BOOST_PP_IIF(COND, EXPORT, IMPORT)()
#define API_IMPL(ARG) API_IMPL2(BOOST_PP_DEFINED(ARG))
#define API(LIB) API_IMPL(LIB ## _COMPILING)

// base.hpp
#include "config.hpp"
class API(LIBBASE) base {
public:
    base();
};

// base.cpp
#include "base.hpp"
base::base() = default;

// derived.hpp
#include "config.hpp"
#include "base.hpp"
class API(LIBDERIVED) derived : public base {
public:
    derived();
};

// derived.cpp
#include "derived.hpp"
derived::derived() = default;
```

In other words, when compiling `base.cpp`, `API(LIBBASE)` would expand to `__declspec(dllexport)` because `LIBBASE_COMPILING` was defined on the command line, but when compiling `derived.cpp` `API(LIBBASE)` would expand to `__declspec(dllimport)` because `LIBBASE_COMPILING` was *not* defined on the command line, but `API(LIBDERIVED)` would now expand to `__declspec(dllexport)` since `LIBDERIVED_COMPILING` would be. But for this to work it is critical that the `API` macro expand contextually.

Comment: Probably not possible in general case, but can be possible with limitations. Do you control how `FOO` is `#define`'d ? Is it you who `#define` it in various places? What type is `FOO` - does it define string, integer, empty definition or something else?

Comment: @Codeguard I do control how ```FOO``` is defined, and in my envisioned usage, I would be setting it on the compile line with -D when certain files are compiled. As such, I could set it to any of the choices you mention.

Comment: If you can choose the value of `FOO`, why not just do `-DFOO=1`, then add a little `#ifndef FOO / #define FOO 0 / #endif` and just use `FOO`.

Comment: This will break if `#ifndef FOO / #define FOO 0 / #endif` gets into precompiled header.

Comment: @rodrigo I added an example to help motivate why I need the contextual expansion, and why just defining and using #if will not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you could use [`BOOST_VMD_IS_EMPTY`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/vmd/doc/html/BOOST_VMD_IS_EMPTY.html) to implement the required behavior. This macro returns `1` if its input is empty or `0` if its input is not empty.

Trick based on the observation that when `XXX` is defined by `#define XXX`, empty parameter list passed to `BOOST_VMD_IS_EMPTY(XXX)` during expansion.

Sample implementation of `MAGIC` macro:

```
#ifndef BOOST_PP_VARIADICS
#define BOOST_PP_VARIADICS
#endif

#include <boost/vmd/is_empty.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/control/iif.hpp>

#define MAGIC(XXX) BOOST_PP_IIF(BOOST_VMD_IS_EMPTY(XXX), 3, 4)

#define XXX
int x = MAGIC(XXX);
#undef XXX
int p = MAGIC(XXX);
```

For Boost 1.62 and VS2015 preprocessor output will be:

```
int x = 3;
int p = 4;
```

This approach has a number of flaws, e.g. it's not working if `XXX` defined with `#define XXX 1`. `BOOST_VMD_IS_EMPTY` itself has [limitations](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/vmd/doc/html/variadic_macro_data/vmd_specific.html).

**EDIT:**

Here is the implementation of the required `API` macros based on `BOOST_VMD_IS_EMPTY`:

```
// config.hpp
#ifndef BOOST_PP_VARIADICS
#define BOOST_PP_VARIADICS
#endif

#include <boost/vmd/is_empty.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/control/iif.hpp>

#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#define IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)

#define API_IMPL2(COND) BOOST_PP_IIF(COND, EXPORT, IMPORT)
#define API_IMPL(ARG) API_IMPL2(BOOST_VMD_IS_EMPTY(ARG))
#define API(LIB) API_IMPL(LIB ## _COMPILING)
```

Let's see what preprocessor will output for:

```
// base.hpp
#include "config.hpp"
class API(LIBBASE) base {
public:
    base();
};
```

When `LIBBASE_COMPILING` defined, GCC output:

```
class __attribute__((dllexport)) Base
{
  public:
    Base();
};
```

When `LIBBASE_COMPILING` is not defined, GCC output:

```
class __attribute__((dllimport)) Base
{
  public:
    Base();
};
```

Tested with VS2015 and GCC 5.4 (Cygwin)

**EDIT 2:**
As @acm mentioned when parameter defined with `-DFOO` it's same as `-DFOO=1` or `#define FOO 1`. In this case approach based on `BOOST_VMD_IS_EMPTY` is not working. To overcome it you can use [`BOOST_VMD_IS_NUMBER`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/vmd/doc/html/BOOST_VMD_IS_NUMBER.html) (thnx to @jv_ for the idea). Implementation:

```
#ifndef BOOST_PP_VARIADICS
#define BOOST_PP_VARIADICS
#endif

#include <boost/vmd/is_number.hpp>
#include <boost/preprocessor/control/iif.hpp>

#define EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#define IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)

#define API_IMPL2(COND) BOOST_PP_IIF(COND, EXPORT, IMPORT)
#define API_IMPL(ARG) API_IMPL2(BOOST_VMD_IS_NUMBER(ARG))
#define API(LIB) API_IMPL(LIB ## _COMPILING)
```

Comment: Very interesting, I will try this today and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: I think the limitation when XXX is defined with `#define XXX 1` can be easily solved using `BOOST_VMD_IS_NUMBER` (analogous to your approach with `BOOST_VMD_IS_EMPTY`). [Here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/X6jKk32fBKAWlpp8) is a possible example (not tested with VS).

Comment: @acm Does it work for you? It's pretty interesting. I'm looking forward for your reply.

Comment: I wasn't able to get it to work on my first try, but have not had much time to get back to this problem. I will definitely update when I have.

Comment: @acm Let me help you a bit. I've used `BOOST_VMD_IS_EMPTY` in your `API` implementation. `API_IMPL2` is also adjusted. Please check the results in the **Edit** section of my answer.

Comment: Ahhh... I figured out what was going wrong. I think in your example you were #define'ing the value in the header. For me, it comes in via -D. A bare -D argument like ```-DFOO``` is the same as `-DFOO=1` - meaning it isn't actually useable with ```BOOST_VMD_IS_EMPTY```, per your mentioned "flaw" above. Passing -DFOO= defines it in such a way that ```BOOST_VMD_IS_EMPTY``` respects it. Neat!

Comment: @acm As @jv_ mention to overcome this problem you can use `BOOST_VMD_IS_NUMBER` instead of `BOOST_VMD_IS_EMPTY`. I've checked it with `-DFOO=1`, it works as expected. I will update my answer.

Comment: Yup, totally working wth ```BOOST_VMD_IS_NUMBER```. I think this might be a better way of doing project wide visibility macros if you are willing to take the preprocessor metaprogramming hit. In projects made up of large number of libraries, it is no fun to need to make a separate config.h header for every library. This way, do it once and make the preprocessor do the heavy lifting.

Comment: `BOOST_VMD_IS_NUMBER` is also useful when you want to detect defines for `SIG*` macros such as whether `SIGHUP` exists in the current system. This and the rest of the answer saved my ass right now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a pure is defined check, but we can get all the way to checking for a particular token name.

Annotating a first principles solution based on [Cloak](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak) from Paul Fultz II:

First provide the ability to conditionally choose text based on macro expansion to 0 or 1

```
#define IIF(bit) PRIMITIVE_CAT(IIF_, bit)
#define IIF_0(t, f) f
#define IIF_1(t, f) t
```

Basic concatenation

```
#define CAT(a, ...) PRIMITIVE_CAT(a, __VA_ARGS__)
#define PRIMITIVE_CAT(a, ...) a##__VA_ARGS__
```

Logical operators (compliment and and)

```
#define COMPL(b) PRIMITIVE_CAT(COMPL_, b)
#define COMPL_0 1
#define COMPL_1 0
#define BITAND(x) PRIMITIVE_CAT(BITAND_, x)
#define BITAND_0(y) 0
#define BITAND_1(y) y
```

A method to see whether a token is or is not parens "()"

```
#define CHECK_N(x, n, ...) n
#define CHECK(...) CHECK_N(__VA_ARGS__, 0, )
#define PROBE(x) x, 1,
#define IS_PAREN(x) CHECK(IS_PAREN_PROBE x)
#define IS_PAREN_PROBE(...) PROBE(~)
```

Note IS_PAREN works because "IS_PAREN_PROBE X" turns in to one arg in CHECK(), where as "IS_PAREN_PROBE ()" turns into PROBE(~) which turns into ~, 1.  At which point we can pick up the 1 from CHECK

Another utility to eat some macro arguments as needed

```
#define EAT(...)
```

Here, we take advantage of blue painting (the thing which prevents naively recursive macros) to check whether or not two tokens are the same.  If they are this collapses to ().  Otherwise not, which we can detect via IS_PAREN.

This relies on COMPARE_XXX identity macros existing for any given symbol

```
#define PRIMITIVE_COMPARE(x, y) IS_PAREN(COMPARE_##x(COMPARE_##y)(()))
```

We add an IS_COMPARABLE trait for that helper

```
#define IS_COMPARABLE(x) IS_PAREN(CAT(COMPARE_, x)(()))
```

We work backwards to EQUAL by checking if both args are comparable, then converting to primitive_compare if they are.  If not, we're not equal and eat the following args.

```
#define NOT_EQUAL(x, y)                             \
    IIF(BITAND(IS_COMPARABLE(x))(IS_COMPARABLE(y))) \
    (PRIMITIVE_COMPARE, 1 EAT)(x, y)
```

EQUAL is the compliment

```
#define EQUAL(x, y) COMPL(NOT_EQUAL(x, y))
```

And finally, the macro we actually want.

First we enable compare for "BUILDING_LIB"

```
#define COMPARE_BUILDING_LIB(x) x
```

Then our actual deciding macro, which is an integer if on whether a symbol resolves to "BUILDING_LIB"

```
#define YES_IF_BUILDING_LIB(name) IIF(EQUAL(name, BUILDING_LIB))("yes", "no")

#include <iostream>

#define FOO BUILDING_LIB

int main(int, char**) {
    std::cout << YES_IF_BUILDING_LIB(FOO) << "\n";
    std::cout << YES_IF_BUILDING_LIB(BAR) << "\n";
}
```

Which outputs:

```
yes
no
```

See his great blogpost (that I cribbed from): [C Preprocessor tricks, tips, and idioms](https://github.com/pfultz2/Cloak/wiki/C-Preprocessor-tricks,-tips,-and-idioms)

Answer (score -1):

Since you intend to use `FOO` as file-level switch that you control, I suggest that you use a simpler solution. The suggested solution is easier to read, less surprising, requires no dirty magic.

Instead of `#define MAGIC(ARG) BOOST_PP_IIF(BOOST_PP_DEFINED(ARG), CHOICE1, CHOICE2)` you simply `-D` with `MAGIC=CHOICE1` or `MAGIC=CHOICE2` per file.

- You don't have to do it for all files. The compiler will tell you when you used `MAGIC` in a file, but did not make a choice.
- If `CHOICE1` or `CHOICE2` is a major default you don't wish to specify, you can use `-D` to set default for all files and `-U` + `-D` to change your decision per file.
- If `CHOICE1` or `CHOICE2` is lengthy, you can `#define CHOICE1_TAG actual_contents` in your header file where you originally intended to define `MAGIC` and then `-D` with `MAGIC=CHOICE1_TAG`, because `CHOICE1_TAG` will be automatically expanded into `actual_contents`.

Comment: I'm not sure I like the goal of the question, but this solution has the unfortunate property of pushing configuration that used to be in the program source code into the build system source (Makefile).

Comment: OP said he's going to use `-D` in his envisioned usage.

Comment: @Codeguard please see my updated question for details on why I need the macro to expand differently in different contexts within the same TU.